# how to solve 3 nonlinear equations in python

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following system of 3 nonlinear equations that I need to solve:

-xyt + HF = 0

-2xzt + 4yzt - xyt + 4z^2t - M1F = 0

-2xt + 2yt + 4zt - 1 = 0

where x, HF, and M1F are known parameters. Therefore, y,z, and t are the parameters to be calculated.

**Attemp to solve the problem:**

```
def equations(p):
    y,z,t = p
    f1 = -x*y*t + HF
    f2 = -2*x*z*t + 4*y*z*t - x*y*t + 4*t*z**2 - M1F
    f3 = -2*x*t + 2*y*t + 4*z*t - 1
    return (f1,f2,f3)

y,z,t = fsolve(equations)

print equations((y,z,t))
```

But the thing is that if I want to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` then I should input an initial guess. In my case, I do not have any initial conditions.

Is there another way to solve 3 nonlinear equations with 3 unknowns in python?

**Edit:**

It turned out that I have a condition! The condition is that HF > M1F, HF > 0, and M1F > 0.

Comment: But I cannot add any initial guess. Is there a way other than using `scipy.optimize`?

Comment: Have you read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542801/solving-non-linear-equations-in-python)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Christian, I don't think the equation system can be linearize easily, unlike the post you suggested.

Powell's Hybrid method (`optimize.fsolve()`) is quite sensitive to initial conditions, so it is very useful if you can come up with a good initial parameter guess. In the following example, we firstly minimize the sum-of-squares of all three equations using Nelder-Mead method (`optimize.fmin()`, for small problem like OP, this is probably already enough). The resulting parameter vector is then used as the initial guess for `optimize.fsolve()` to get the final result.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> from scipy import optimize
>>> HF, M1F, x=1000.,900.,10.
>>> def f(p):
    return abs(sum(array(equations(p))**2)-0)
>>> optimize.fmin(f, (1.,1.,1.))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 131
         Function evaluations: 239
array([ -8.95023217,   9.45274653, -11.1728963 ])
>>> optimize.fsolve(equations, (-8.95023217,   9.45274653, -11.1728963))
array([ -8.95022376,   9.45273632, -11.17290503])
>>> pr=optimize.fsolve(equations, (-8.95023217,   9.45274653, -11.1728963))
>>> equations(pr)
(-7.9580786405131221e-13, -1.2732925824820995e-10, -5.6843418860808015e-14)
```

The result is pretty good.