# What's the difference in the use and precision of fsolve, brentq and root for a system of equations?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I have asked this question [Is fsolve good to any system of equations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128989/is-fsolve-good-to-any-system-of-equations), from which I got a satisfactory answer. The system I presented there

> x = A * exp (x+y)
>
> y = 4 * exp (x+y)

, is just a toy model which is similar with my real case problem, `fsolve` did the work with (code in the answer below):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def f(p,*args):
  x, y = p
  A = args[0] 
 
  return (x -A* np.exp(x+y),y- 4* np.exp(x+y))
A = np.linspace(0,4,5)
X = []
Y =[]
for a in A:
  x,y =  fsolve(f,(0.0, 0.0) , args=(a))
  X.append(x)
  Y.append(y)
  print(x,y)

plt.plot(A,X)
plt.plot(A,Y)
```

However, I read here stackoverflow.com/questions/6519380/… that `brenqt` is much faster than `fsolve`. I've tried then to use it but keep getting `f(a) and f(b) must have different signs`. I understand that `f must be continuous. f(a) and f(b) must have opposite signs.` So, I believe `brenqt` is not a good choice for this system. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

In my real case I'm encountering exactly what the answer here [how to solve 3 nonlinear equations in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827005/how-to-solve-3-nonlinear-equations-in-python) says, i.e."fsolve()) is quite sensitive to initial conditions" I want to avoid to "firstly minimize the sum-of-squares" as I have many more parameters than the OP of that question. How to use `optimize.root` to produce a similar result as the one I got with `fsolve` in my original question?

Comment: Regarding `brentq`: Take a look at the [section of the documentation page for `scipy.optimize` about "Root finding"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).  Note that `brentq` is listed in the section *Scalar functions*.  Then take a look at the [docstring for `brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq); it talks about find a root in an *interval* [a, b].  So `brentq` is for finding the root of a scalar function (scalar input, scalar output).  That's why you were having trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand (thanks to the comment above) that the `brentq` only works for scalar functions. I did found a good solution with `optimize.root` and it gives a good solution with some of their available methods, for example:

```
def f(p,*args):
   x,y = p
   A = args[0] 
   return (x -A* np.exp(x+y),y- 4* np.exp(x+y))
A = np.linspace(0,4,5)
X = []
Y =[]
for a in A: 
   sol=optimize.root(f,[1.0,10.0],args=(a),method='lm')
   sol.message
   x,y= sol.x[0],sol.x[1]
   X.append(x)
   Y.append(y)
   print(x,y)
plt.plot(A,X)
plt.plot(A,Y)
```

I'm still struggling to get an appropriate `method` to my system, as the solver is extremely sensitive to it. For example, if I use `method='broyden'` in the same code above I get a completely different solution.
I'll post another question to ask for help.