# Strategies to solve systems of multidimensional nonlinear equations with scipy and Mathematica

Tags: python, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve and reproduce a solution of a system of non-linear equations using scipy.
I've learned a lot from different posts, and I could figure out some issues I had [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581064/whats-the-difference-in-the-use-and-precision-of-fsolve-brentq-and-root-for-a).
It seems, however, based on the solution I posted above to my own question, that `scipy.optimize` is quite sensitive to the different [available methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root)
I'm trying to use [nonlinear solvers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html) as someone else pointed this here but I'm getting the same solutions, which I suppose are wrong. I say this because in the scientific paper I'm following (and trying to reproduce the results) they solved the same system with `Mathematica`, and got a different result which is more close to what one would expect. In the past, I only posted a minimal work example of my code, but now I decided to post the real thing.

I was wondering if `Mathematica` could easily manage the choice of the solver and tackle the problem. I initially wanted to preferably use Python, but right now my priority is to solve this problem, no matter the language. If someone figures out a way to solve with `scipy` much better.

Follow my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize


c1 = 43.524e-3 

Z1 = 1 

Z2 = 3  

b = 1.7e-10 

q = 1.6e-19

k_B = 1.38e-23

T = 296.15

N = 6.02e23

lB=0.71e-9

xi = 4.2

v1 = 4*np.pi*np.exp(1.0)*N*(1.0+Z1)*(xi-Z1**(-1.0))*b**(3.0)
v2 = 4*np.pi*np.exp(1.0)*N*(1.0+Z2)*(xi-Z2**(-1.0))*b**(3.0) 
epsilon =  q**2/(xi*k_B*T*b)
I = 46.311e-3


kappa2 = (3.29e7)*c1**(0.5) * (1e2)


def f(p,*args):
    theta1,theta2 = p
    c2 = args[0]
    eq1 = theta1-(c1*v1/10**3)*np.exp(-1-2*Z1*xi*(1-Z1*theta1-Z2*theta2)*np.log(1-np.exp(-kappa2*b)))
    eq2 =  theta2-c2*((v2/(10**3*np.exp(1)))*((10**3*theta1*np.exp(1))/(c1*v1))**3)   
    return(eq1,eq2)



c2 =  np.arange(0,150e-6,1e-6)

THETA1 = []
THETA2 =[]
THETA = []
for i in c2:

    sol=optimize.root(f,np.array([0.12024367, 0.00062351]),args=(i),method='hybr')
    theta1,theta2 = sol.x[0],sol.x[1]
    sol.message
    theta=3*theta2+theta1
    THETA1.append(theta1)
    THETA2.append(theta2) 
    THETA.append(theta)
    print (theta1,theta2,theta)
```

What is supposedly wrong is that `theta1` drops down extremelly fast, the numerical values for the two first interaction are:

```
theta1,theta2,theta
0.12154778645003049, 6.444608966498463e-30, 0.12154778645003049
6.961522754431233e-05, 0.17477403029874458, 0.5243917061237781
```

And here is an evolution of theta1, theta2 and theta as a function of c2.

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Results from the aforementioned paper:

[image]

Comment: Did you print `sol.success` after each call of `root()`?

Comment: I just did and got `True`

Comment: I ran your code, and then double-checked that `f(sol.x, i)` was, in fact, approximately (0, 0) for each i.  If those results don't agree with the paper, you should double-check that you formulated the problem in the same way as the paper.

Comment: My main concern is if Mathematica could be a more robust way to solve this. I've tried different options for `method=` and it seems that `scipy` is extremely sensitive to it. I was wondering how would be the case for an equivalent solver in Mathematica.

Comment: Nothing that you have shown suggests that the scipy solver is not working.  Have you double-checked your translation from Mathematica to Python?  You have two versions of `eq2` in the code--are you using the correct version?  Can you include the Mathematica code in the question?

Comment: (Ignore the comment about two versions of `eq2`--I just noticed that you edited it out.)

Comment: I haven't done anything with Mathematica. I coded from scratch in Python and based on several other posts I thought that Mathematica is perhaps more robust in the sense that, I suppose, it has fewer options.  Also, the initial guess in`scipy` is somehow a problem, it seems. I will look for the posts that report it.  I had two versions of `eq2` but the lastest I'm using is the one I posted. I'll edit my question to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without more concrete evidence that something is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I added the graph from the paper. But still, I understand that that doesn't add a lot to the discussion.

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with your translation of the formulas from the paper into Python, maybe even just a small typo.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the paper you used? I hope that should help